# Why doesn't this Python code cause an endless loop in __hash__?

Tags: python, circular-reference

I'm a python newb and I'm just trying to understand the logic [here](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=115):

```
class SomeClass:

    #...
    def __hash__(self):
        return self.__str__().__hash__()

    def __str__(self):        
        arr = []
        if self.final: 
            arr.append("1")
        else:
            arr.append("0")

        for (label, node) in self.edges.iteritems():
            arr.append( label )
            arr.append( str( node.id ) )

        return "_".join(arr)

    #...

someObj = SomeClass()  
hash(someObj)
```

The way I'm reading it is this:

If I try to call `hash()` function on object of class SomeClass -> then `__hash__` magic method will be executed. `__hash__` method calls `__str__` method and then calls `__hash__` method second time on a result of a `__str__` method -> which imho results in circular reference and endless loop...

Could someone explain to me - how is this not an endless loop with `__hash__` being called over and over again?

Comment: I assume that __str__() changes this object into a string, which means that you would be calling the __hash__() method of the String class, not of this class

Comment: Presumably, `__str__` returns a string, which is then hashed. Unless `SomeClass.__str__` is implemented as `return self` (which it really shouldn't be!) this is absolutely fine - you're hashing a string object, not a `SomeClass` instance (i.e. calling `str.__hash__`, not `SomeClass.__hash__`).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I honestly just took a code [from here](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=115). Yes -> __str__ returns a string.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ahh. gotcha. I understand the logic now.

Comment: @Dannyboy please edit the question to include a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (i.e. at least `__hash__` and `__str__`) so that we don't have to read the whole post, and so that this question remains relevant if that post ever goes offline.

Comment: That code should be written as `return hash(str(self))`.

Comment: @Matthias:  Perhaps `return self.__str__().__hash__()` was meant as an optimization (albeit a poor one), but `return hash(str(self))` certainly is the pythonic way of writing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you were just calling `self.__hash__()` from within `__hash__()`, then you would have an endless loop, for certain. However, you're calling `self.__str__().__hash__()` instead.

The `__str__()` method returns a string object as it tends to do, which means that `self.__str__().__hash__()` is calling the `__hash__` method of an entirely different class (String) - and thus, you're not actually calling the same function again. That's why you don't have an endless loop.